# Use copy of outside variable inside closure

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I'm trying to use Cairo with Rust and came to a problem where I can't find a good solution for:

```
let (width, height) = (400., 300.);

let window = gtk::ApplicationWindow::new(application);
window.set_default_size(width as i32, height as i32);

let drawing_area = Box::new(DrawingArea::new)();

drawing_area.connect_draw(|_, cr| {
    cr.scale(width, height);
    ...
    });
```

I assumed I could use `width` and `height` directly inside the closure since those are primitive types that are copied by default. Yet the compiler complains:

```
   |     drawing_area.connect_draw(|_, cr| {
   |                               ^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `width`
```

I couldn't find a good solution for this issue in the Rust documentation, what is the best way to use outside variables inside a closure?

I can't change the signature of the closure since `connect_draw` expects exactly two input parameters.

Comment: Have you tried `move |_, cr|` ?

Comment: Wouldn't `move` take over ownership of `width`? I need it later on in my main function again.

Comment: No, because it implements the copy trait, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.tuple.html#trait-implementations

Comment: You are right @hellow. Thank you, I didn't know it would automatically copy the value.